How can I create a product of a 2-dimensional list with a 1-dimensional list (needs to be one-liner)?
I have two lists that I'm trying to combine:
lst1 = [['arg1', 'arg2']]  # this can have more lists, but for simplicity, leaving it as this
lst2 = ['arg3', 'arg4']

I want the product of the two lists so that the product is:
[
  ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'],
  ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg4'],
]

I can obviously loop through and do this, but I need to be able to do this as a one-liner (I have reasons).
I've been able to do this by doing the following:
list(
    map(
        lambda l: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l)),
        list(itertools.product(lst, lst2)),
    )
)

edit: I think the above answer worked for me when I mapped the 1d list so every element was inside a list, which is super ugly. e.g. lst2 was actually list(map(lambda a: [a], lst2))
...which is okay, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. I also feel like there should be a more mathematical way to express what I'm describing? Maybe itertools isn't the right library?

This is a perfectly ordinary Cartesian product of multiple lists - one list's elements are strings, and the other's are lists. Then for each result in the Cartesian product, you do a little manipulation to join the string onto the list. The reason your attempt looks ugly (it's still fundamentally the right approach) is because you're going out of your way to create a lambda suitable for map, and then coercing the result to a list, instead of just using a list comprehension for the task that it's designed for.

(And also because you're invoking itertools.chain.from_iterable to join exactly two lists - one of which you get from wrapping the lst2 elements - instead of just concatenating them with +.)

Here is one solution which use itertools.product:
import itertools
lst1 = [['arg1', 'arg2']]
lst2 = ['arg3', 'arg4']
out = [sub_list + [element] for sub_list, element in itertools.product(lst1, lst2)]
print(out)

Output:
[['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'], ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg4']]



Avoid list(map(lambda)). Use a list comprehension instead.

Then you can also use unpacking to give individual names to the product elements


There's no need to do list(product)
Your chain doesn't actually work. Instead you can put the 1D elements in a list and add.

>>> [e1 + [e2] for e1, e2 in itertools.product(lst1, lst2)]
[['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'], ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg4']]


You just want
[[*sub, x] for sub in list1 for x in list2]

